# Image not getting visible in codeigniter application

Tags: php, html, linux, codeigniter

I have an application developed in codeigniter in which there is a photo upload feature. It works fine and photo gets uploaded to the required path successfully. However when opening the application. it shows a broken image. If I inspect the element and copy paste the URL of the image in the new tab it gives 404 error, but when I refresh the same tab in which Image URL is open it opens up and shows the image. The server on which application is hosted is godaddy.

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
 <div class="thumbnail">
  <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>special_instructions/1454479436_IMG_20160118_154912.jpg" target="_blank">
   <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>special_instructions/1454479436_IMG_20160118_154912.jpg" class="img-rounded">
  </a>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: It seems you have enabled .htaccess url rewrite feature. And when you open image, its pointed on index page, which shows 404. This is just a guess.

Comment: It sounds like you might have an .htaccess permissions problem.

Comment: But.. when I copy paste the URL in other tab the image opens fine!

Comment: Is there any reason why your having image link in the `a href=""` you also I thing it only should be in img.

Comment: Yes there is a reason, I need to open the image in the new tab

Comment: pls set height and width in img tag and check it

Comment: Can you show us the error.log and the full url of the image?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to disable the hot link protection from Cpanel!!  It worked. But are there any serious consequences of disabling hot link protection?