# Lock on a folder in Directory privacy in Cpanel?

Tags: php, cpanel

With reference to my earlier post in which I had mentioned   [the problem of images not visible in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35263668/image-not-getting-visible-in-codeigniter-application?noredirect=1#comment58327277_35263668). I have found the solution my disabling the hot link protection. But the images still need to be displayed!. 
Then I found out the core of the problem that the folder is showing a lock symbol and other folders do not seem to have a lock symbol and those applications are working fine and displaying images. All I need to remove this lock !!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have protected your directory with the password and due to that lock box is appears in your directory listing, Please try to remove that password protections and then check your images. You can access your images when you remove password protection from your directory